# Data Annotations Multiple DataType's for a property

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, data-annotations

Is it possible to assign both MultiLine and Html Datatypes to a property using data annotations?

Comment: Both are stored as strings in .net and `varchar` in database. What is the problem here?

Comment: im talking about how it will be scaffolded I guess